# Qt: "normal" window size lost when switching to maximized state and then to fullscreen

Tags: qt, window, size, fullscreen

I have an Qt application that can be displayed either "normal" (a normal window that's neither maximized nor minimized), maximized or fullscreen. I achieve that by calling the functions `QWidget::showNormal()`, `QWidget::showMaximized()` and `QWidget::showFullscreen()`.

Let me first of all explain what does work:

1. Going from normal to maximized and back works. Qt remembers the window size and position of the normal window and then restores that when exiting the maximized state.
2. Going from normal to fullscreen and back works. Also here the size and position of the normal window is maintained.

What doesn't work?

When going from normal to maximized, then to fullscreen, back to maximized and then back to normal that does not work as expected. The window will not be resized to the size that it had originally, before maximizing. Instead the window will be as large as the screen (basically as large as the OS allows the window to be).

If I now go to fullscreen again then in the right upper corner and on the bottom edge there are weird artifacts that seem to look like parts of an old Vista window frame with visual effects disabled.

Here is an image that should illustrate the process I just explained:

[image]

I tried to save the last size of the window using `QWidget::saveGeometry()` or just saving the size obtained by `QWidget::size()` when a window state change event occured, but there were always cases when it behaved strangely. Apart from that, that last step when going full screen again looks like a bug to me.

What do you think?

UPDATE:

If I resize the window manually (to an arbitrary size) before the last step (which is going to fullscreen again), the fullscreen works without problems.

Comment: Could you please add the Qt version you're using? This is important in case it might be a bug.

Comment: It's the latest one, 5.5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new Qt 5.6 release apparently fixed that bug.

Answer (score 4):

Try doing `showNormal()` before `showFullScreen()` when the window is maximised and going to fullscreen.

when going to fullscreen

```
if (wasMaximized = isMaximized())
{
    setVisible(false);  // prevents window animation on showNormal() call 
    showNormal();
    setVisible(true);
}
showFullScreen();
```

when returning from fullscreen

```
if (isFullScreen())
{
    if (wasMaximized)
        showMaximized();
    else
        showNormal();
}
```

Comment: This works as a workaround, but it's not so nice. Even with the `setVisible` the screen falshes white for a moment. I just wish they fixed that bug...(maybe I'll try the new 5.6 release)

Comment: The 5.6 release apparently really fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

This will helpful for you

```
void toggleFullScreen()
{
    if (isFullScreen()) {
        if (wasMaximized) {
            showMaximized();
        } else {
            showNormal();
        }
    } else {
        wasMaximized = isMaximized();
        showFullScreen();
    }
}
```

You need to declare `wasMaximized` yourself (It must be a global variable for you MainWindow class)

I have a bad English, so I can't explain all of this code. Sorry